# Inputting a mathematical function and differentiating it in matlab

Tags: matlab, differentiation

I am new to matlab and want to calculate something like f(x)/f'(x). I want the user to input the function f(x), the parameter x and a value of x (suppose 5,so that I can evaluate f(5)/f'(5)) .Please suggest what I should do.

Comment: Do you have symbolic toolbox?  There are two very different approaches depending on whether or not you use it.

Comment: Be sure to let me know if the answer I have provided works for you.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt :I searched around and found a method to input a function,its parameter and the value but NOT the differentiation. However, I would be grateful I you could tell me about the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use symbolic variables

```
function [ val ] = func( fun, num )
    symfun = sym(fun);
    dsymfun = diff(symfun);
    y = symfun/dsymfun;
    val = subs(y, num);
end
```

and then call it

e.g.

```
value = func('x^2', 5)

value =

5/2
```

Otherwise, you can provide your input as a symbolic variable:

```
function [ val ] = func( fun, num )
    dfun = diff(fun);
    y = fun/dfun;
    val = subs(y, num);
end
```

and then write

```
syms x;
func(x^2, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks @ nikaltipar The program is correct. But I need to input the function f as well as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [**`polyder`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyder.html) and [**`polyval`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) as follows:

```
f = input('Enter f(x): '); %e.g; Enter [1 3 4]  if f(x)= x^2 + 3*x + 4
df = polyder(f);           %f'(x)
x= input('Enter x:  ');    %Enter the value of 'x' e.g 5
fx_dfx= polyval(f,x)/ polyval(df,x)    %f(x)/f'(x)
```

If you have ***Symbolic Math Toolbox***, you can also do this using:

```
syms x;                      %Creating a symbolic variable x
f = input('Enter f(x): ');   %Enter f(x) e.g: x^2 + 3*x + 4
f(x)= f;                     %Converting sym to symfun
df(x) = diff(f)              %f'(x)
x_val= input('Enter x:  ');  %Enter the value of 'x' e.g 5
fx_dfx = double(f(x_val)/df(x_val)) %f(x)/f'(x)
```